# Getting improper sequence values in oracle 10g

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g

getting improper sequence values while inserting record using hibernate ,sequence increments value by 2 .why it is happening

```
CREATE TABLE  "DOCTOR" 
   (    "DOCTOR_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DOCTOR_NAME" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "PLACE" VARCHAR2(40), 
    "PHONE_NUMBER" NUMBER(10,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "DOCTOR_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DOCTOR_ID") ENABLE
   )
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_DOCTOR" 
  before insert on "DOCTOR"               
  for each row  
begin   
    select "DOCTOR_SEQ1".nextval into :NEW.DOCTOR_ID from dual; 
end; 

/
 ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_DOCTOR" ENABLE

    DOCTOR_SEQ1:
    Min Value   1
    Max Value   999999999999999999999999999
    Increment By    1
    Cycle Flag  N
    Order Flag  N
    Cache Size  20
    Last Number 261
```

And config for hibernate

```
hbm:
      <id name="doctorId" type="long">
            <column name="DOCTOR_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence" >
                <param name="sequence">DOCTOR_SEQ1</param>
            </generator>
        </id>



  obtained values
    245 ramesh  knr 8080808080
    243 chakri  hyd 9090909090
    247 rameshreddy knr 8080808080
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the sequence values you obtained ?

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle docs ,

*CACHE Specify how many values of the sequence the database preallocates and keeps in memory for faster access. This integer value can have 28 or fewer digits. The minimum value for this parameter is 2. For sequences that cycle, this value must be less than the number of values in the cycle. You cannot cache more values than will fit in a given cycle of sequence numbers.

Therefore, the maximum value allowed for CACHE must be less than the value determined by the following formula:

(CEIL (MAXVALUE - MINVALUE)) / ABS (INCREMENT)

If a system failure occurs, then all cached sequence values that have not been used in committed DML statements are lost. The potential number of lost values is equal to the value of the CACHE parameter.*

**Note:
Oracle recommends using the CACHE setting to enhance performance if you are using sequences in an Oracle Real Application Clusters environment.**

**NOCACHE:**  Specify NOCACHE to indicate that values of the sequence are not preallocated. If you omit both CACHE and NOCACHE, then the database caches 20 sequence numbers by default.

Also [read this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF54244)
So try with this sequence ,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE doctor
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

And the `Order Flag` needs to be `Y` to generate sequences in order

Hope this helps !!

Comment: it is still increments by 2 only

Answer (score 0):

The reason the sequence is incrementing by 2 each time is that there are two systems both getting values from the sequence.

1. Hibernate is getting a sequence value, e.g. `1`
2. Hibernate then inserts the row into the table
3. Your trigger fires, gets a new sequence value, e.g. `2`, and overwrites the ID

Either stop Hibernate from using the sequence, or remove/disable the trigger, or if you still need the trigger for other non-Hibernate systems, modify it to only get an ID if required:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_DOCTOR" 
  before insert on "DOCTOR"               
  for each row  
  when new.doctor_id is null
begin   
    select "DOCTOR_SEQ1".nextval into :NEW.DOCTOR_ID from dual; 
end; 
/
```